# Magnific Popup Callback when close

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I'm creating popup using method http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api -> Public methods.

```
    $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#createTableBooking', 
                type: 'inline'
            }
    });
```

I want to call function when this exact popup close.

Comment: Your answer is in the link you gave...? See the `callbacks` object. There's a `close` property.

Comment: If you are suggesting "$.magnificPopup.close();", This is not what i wanted. I want call back function when close method run.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting `$('.image-link').magnificPopup({ callbacks: { close: function() { /* your logic here */ } });`

Comment: The thing is I'm not opening popup using  your suggested method. I'm using method that i have post on my answer.

Comment: As alternative, you could try fancybox, it is so simple - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPYjxN?editors=1010 (yes, I am the author and sorry that my answer is not about script you are using)

Comment: @Janis. Thanks for the comment. I'll use it for my next project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the JSFiddle for what u needed [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tf6Lu41o/). Here in the code you can use your own div id like you have used in your case, in the `src` field. Your code was missing the extra function call which would be made when we close the popup.

Here in the code, a function call is made before closing the popup as you needed.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @SameeraLiyanage fingers crossed :-D